# How to destructure Objects from API?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm calling an API from (https://reqres.in/api/users), can we destructure this API into a single array of object. So that I can customize per-page which is fixed in the API.

```
This is Codepen link https://codepen.io/monukr14/pen/oOWpyq



Initial API Format

{
  "page": 1,
  "per_page": 3,
  "total": 12,
  "total_pages": 4,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "first_name": "George",
      "last_name": "Bluth",
      "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "first_name": "Janet",
      "last_name": "Weaver",
      "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/josephstein/128.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "first_name": "Emma",
      "last_name": "Wong",
      "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/olegpogodaev/128.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what you are asking. Do you mean how you can get the `data` array in a separate variable? `const { data } = response;`

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ? Question isn't clear codepen mentioned in question show everything working fine

Comment: I want that in a single page all 12 data should be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are going to have to make several API calls, all based on the previous call. [This is pretty much the example case for `async await`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

```
// default start at page #1
async function makeRequest(page = 1) {
    const url = `https://reqres.in/api/users?page=${page}`
    const response = await axios.get(url);

    const { total_pages: totalPages, data } = response.data;

    const isLastPage = totalPages <= page;
    if (isLastPage) {
        return data; // if last page, just return this data
    }

    const next = await makeRequest(page + 1); // make request for next page
    return [...next, ...data] // return both sets of data
}
```

This is a function that handles the making of the requests. It recursively calls the API if there are more pages to get.

We can then handle it nicely in your `componentDidMount` method.

```
componentDidMount() {
  makeRequest()
    .then(repos => this.setState({ repos }))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

=== EDIT ===

On second thought, I want to update my previous answer as it isn't scalable.
It shows all of the users after all the requests had been made - unnoticeable at 4 pages but would be an issue at larger number of pages.

```
async function makeRequest(page = 1) {
  const url = `https://reqres.in/api/users?page=${page}`;
  const response = await axios.get(url);

  const { total_pages: totalPages, data } = response.data;

  return { totalPages, repos: data };
}

class Repos extends React.Component {
  state = {
    repos: []
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.loadPages();
  }

  async loadPages() {
    const totalPages = await this.loadPage(1); // make first request

    const nextPage = 2;
    for (let i = nextPage; i <= totalPages; i++) { // make every request separately
      this.loadPage(i);
    }
  }

  async loadPage(page = 1) {
    const { totalPages, repos } = await makeRequest(page);
    this.addRepos(repos);

    return totalPages;
  }

  addRepos(repos) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      repos: [...repos, ...prevState.repos] // add to array, not override
    }));
  }
....
}
```

My updated code makes each request separately and appends to the state (rather than overriding it). This means it can make requests independently and add users as soon as each requests complete.

It does mean the order doesn't necessarily match the API, but this can be changes by sorting the state as desired.

[You can see it working on CodePen here.](https://codepen.io/CameronDowner/pen/EJmdzr)